# Авторизация на сайте с помощью python, requests

Tags: python, post, requests

Как бы не крутил код, выдаёт ошибку "Неверный логин или пароль".
[Сайт](https://distant.donnuet.ru/login/index.php)

Вот код

```
headers = {
    "User-Agent": *agent*
}

data = {
    "username": "login",
    "password": "password"
}



def login():
    s = requests.Session()

    loging = s.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)


    f = open('results.html', 'w', encoding='utf8')
    f.write(loging.text)
    f.close()
login()
```

Comment: там в форме есть еще `logintoken` с CSRF токеном, которые нужно передать на сервер

Comment: А как это сделать?

Comment: сначала получить форму, извлечь значение токена, потом отправить форму...вполне возможно что там нужно еще и куки отслеживать все это время

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну например так:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://distant.donnuet.ru/login/index.php'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0',
}
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
res = s.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')

data = {
    'anchor': '',
    'logintoken': soup.find('input', {"name": "logintoken"}).get("value"),
    'username': 'admin',
    'password': '123456',
}

response = s.post('https://distant.donnuet.ru/login/index.php', data=data)
```